# change column name in table

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns

**How  can I change my column in table?**

I try these codes to change it but it doesnt work.

If I will run that it will result as an

> 'Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype
>   (COLUMN) is wrong.'

Here is my code:

```
exec sp_rename 'EMPLOYEE.COMMISSION_PCT', 'COMMISSION', 'COLUMN'

SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com]

Comment: Do you have column called `COMMISSION_PCT` in `EMPLOYEE`  table

Comment: your table is called `EMPLOYEES` not `EMPLOYEE`...right? it seems you have a typo

Comment: @ElmerDantas - Eagle eyes man.. `exec sp_rename 'EMPLOYEES.COMMISSION_PCT', 'COMMISSION', 'COLUMN'`

Comment: @ElmerDantas oh... its really work. thank you so much...

Comment: @jondygonzales hahaha ok..i didn't understand whether works or not. I'm glad to have helped

Comment: @ElmerDantas - this is my first time to post it and i'm a begineer... you really really help me for my project..thank a lot again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried here and work properly.
open another tab and try to do this way.

```
USE [YOUR DATABASE]
GO
exec sp_RENAME 'TABLE.Column', 'NewColumnName',
 'COLUMN'
GO
```

Comment: thats great really helpful